# Attempting to use JOIN on CTEs but getting an error the table was not found

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, common-table-expression

In Big Query I'm using the Austin Bike Share database. I'm attempting to create a new table which contains the subscriber types for bikeshare program, and the count of each subscriber type in 2021 and in 2022.

I'm creating two CTEs with counts for 2021 and then for 2022. Here is an example of my code and the resulting table for 2021:

```
--View subscriber counts for 2021
    WITH subscriber_count2021 AS (
        SELECT 
            count(*) AS subscriber_count_2021,
            subscriber_type
        FROM `adroit-petal-123456.bikeshare_trips.bikes_cleaned`
        WHERE year = 2021
        GROUP BY subscriber_type
        ORDER BY subscriber_count_2021 desc
    )

    SELECT subscriber_count_2021 > subscriber_type
    FROM subscriber_count2021
```

[Resulting table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuBo0.jpg)

Now I'm trying to JOIN my two tables so I can have a count of my subscription types for 2021 and 2022 in one place. However, my attempt is resulting in error message: Table "subscriber_count2021" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table).

```sql
--Compare subscriber counts for 2021 and 2022
    SELECT 
        subscriber_counts2021.*,
        subscriber_counts_2022.*
    FROM subscriber_count2021 JOIN 
        subscriber_count2022 ON subscriber_count2021.subscriber_type 
 = subscriber_count2022.subscriber_type
```

Based on other Stack Overflow posts this seems to be an issue with my aliasing in Big Query. I've attempted:

- Using `` characters around my tables
- Adding the table name as well as my CTE names ex FROM `adroit-petal-123456.bikeshare_trips.bikes_cleaned.subscriber_count2021`
- Updating the SELECT statement to have table.column for each field I'm trying to use for my new table.

None of these seem to resolve the issue I'm facing.

Comment: Seeing the entire query may help. Also, you have periods in odd spots in your query above, such as `subscriber_counts_2022. FROM... `. What is that period doing between `2022` and `FROM`?

Comment: Apologies, when I added my code, I didn't account for Stackover Flow interpreting * as italic type. So the code you are referring to is actually: 
SELECT
  subscriber_counts2021.*
  subscriber_counts2022.*
FROM subscriber_counts2021 JOIN
  subscriber_counts22
ON subscriber_count2021.subscriber_type = subscriber_count2022.subscriber_type

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of typos in the above. The structure appears to be correct, however you're misnaming tables throughout.

Youre interchanging the word `count` and `counts` all over the place. You also appeared to be missing a closing parenthese around your cte.

Below, I standardized the table names to be plural `subscriber_counts_202#` and adjusted the column names to be singular `subscriber_count_202#`

It doesn't really matter which way you go with it, however the important thing is that you appropriately name your columns consistently, your tables consistently, and that you use the correct names in the correct places.

```
--View subscriber counts for 2021
    WITH subscriber_counts2021 AS (
        SELECT 
            count(*) AS subscriber_count_2021,
            subscriber_type
        FROM `adroit-petal-123456.bikeshare_trips.bikes_cleaned`
        WHERE year = 2021
        GROUP BY subscriber_type
        ORDER BY subscriber_count_2021 desc
    )

    SELECT subscriber_count_2021 > subscriber_type
    FROM subscriber_counts2021

--Compare subscriber counts for 2021 and 2022
    SELECT 
        subscriber_counts2021.*,
        subscriber_counts_2022.*
    FROM subscriber_counts2021 JOIN 
        subscriber_counts2022 ON subscriber_counts2021.subscriber_type 
 = subscriber_counts2022.subscriber_type
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I see what you mean where I switched from using singular and plural counts in my above code. I appreciate your correction on this. 

I followed your solution, and while it made sense, it resulted in the same error code “Table subscriber_counts2021” must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table)

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a dataset identifier then. You're doing something like `table.column` and it wants `datasetname.table.column`